# Rails ActiveRecord find children where attribute is NOT a given value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Given that a `Parent` has many `Child`s with `status_id` attribute, I want to find all the children that do NOT have a `status_id:1`. In other words, the `status_id` could be `nil` or a different value. But I'm seeing some interesting behavior:

```
Parent.find(1).childs.where(status_id:nil)
=> #<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation [#<Child id: 1, status_id: nil ...>]

Parent.find(1).childs.where.not(status_id:1)
=> #<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation []>
```

Comment: You can write as: `Parent.find(1).childs.where("status_id != 1")` or 
`Parent.find(1).childs.where("status_id != ?", 1)`

Comment: @KhanhPham that doesn't work either.... still get `=> #<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation []>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This post](https://forum.upcase.com/t/why-does-where-not-on-string-columns-ignores-null-values/3167)   suggests that SQL treats NULL, the absence of something, as something that can't be equal to something that exists.

[10 things in MySQL that won’t work as expected](https://dzone.com/articles/10-things-mysql-won%E2%80%99t-work) has an example which requires using "IS" for null check, something like below.

`Parent.find(1).childs.where("status_id != ? or status_id is null", 1)`

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
Parent.find(1).childs.where("status_id IS NOT 1")
```

Would still love an explanation as to why though

Answer (score 0):

find will through an exception if row is not present

```
parent = Parent.where(id: 1).includes(:childs).first
parent.childs.where("status_id IS NOT 1") if parent.present?
```