# Works in SQLite but not in PostGreSQL... attribute IS NOT 1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have a statement in my code:

```
RentalItem.last.maintenance_orders.where("status_id IS NOT 2").present?
```

Works fine in development mode, but not in PostGreSQL in production. Trouble is, that syntax was the only way of making the code work because in my statement, if a child `maintenance_order` had a `status_id` of `nil`, then I want it to be found by the `.present?` command. Other syntaxes were ignoring `nil`. See this question here: [Rails ActiveRecord find children where attribute is NOT a given value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38258316/rails-activerecord-find-children-where-attribute-is-not-a-given-value)

Any ideas on how to change this syntax?

Comment: Why are you ignoring the answer you accepted to your other question? `is not 2` is not valid SQL so PostgreSQL complains. Also, developing on SQLite and deploying on PostgreSQL is a terrible idea; develop, test, and deploy on the same database or you're in for a world of confusion and bugs.

Comment: lol you're right, i accepted that answer and changed the code, but forgot to commit those changes, and so had the original bad `IS NOT` code. thanks for your comments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
RentalItem.last.maintenance_orders.where("status_id <> 2 or status_id is null").present?
```

Comment: "status_id <> 2 or status_id is null"